# What does "structural" mean in marginal structural models and structural nested models?

Tags: causality

Robins developed the marginal structural models and the structural nested models. An example of the structural nested models is

$$E[Y^a-Y^{a=0}\mid A=a, L]=\beta_1a + \beta_2aL,$$
where $Y^a$ is the counterfactual outcome, $A$ is the treatment, $L$ is the covariate vector.

I have a background in machine learning but I'm new to causal inference. To me, the structural nested model is simply a regression model. What does the word "structural" mean here? How it's different from a regression model?

Thanks!

Edit:
In section 2.1 of this paper "Simulating from marginal structural
models with time-dependent confounding", the authors say that "the term "structural" distinguished it as an interventional model, versus some observational marginal model $P(Y|A=a)$."

Comment: If you really want to study MSM, need to find/understand the difference between $pr[Y_{a_0}=1]$ and $pr[Y=1|A_0=a_0]$ in Section 3 on Robins paper "marginal structural models and causal inference in epidemiology" Epidemiology Sep 2000

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand the difference between $pr[Y_{a0}=1]$ and $pr[Y=1|A_0=a_0]$, the former is the true counterfactual distribution, and the latter is the observational distribution for the observational data collected by a specific policy. Did you mean that the difference between a regression model and an MSM is that a regression model is fitting $Y|A_0=a_0$ while the structural model is modeling $Y_{a0}$? Still, I don't get the point why the model is called structural? I'd appreciate it if you could share some insights about the meaning of the word "structural".

Comment: I have just started reading What if and found this model. What makes this model nested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading more papers from Hernan, I found that the word "structural" simply has the meaning "causal".